# Tornado diagram using ggplot2, ordered by descending order of bin-count

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm looking for a way to create a [tornado diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_diagram) using ggplot2. The example for [geom_linerange](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_linerange.html) comes close:

```
library(ggplot2)
dmod <- lm(price ~ cut, data=diamonds)
cuts <- data.frame(cut=unique(diamonds$cut),
          predict(dmod, data.frame(cut = unique(diamonds$cut)),
          se=TRUE)[c("fit","se.fit")])
se <- ggplot(cuts, aes(cut, fit, ymin = fit - se.fit,
        ymax=fit + se.fit, colour = cut))+ geom_linerange(size=2) + coord_flip()
se
```

But the  lines should be ordered descending by length, i.e. the widest range on top. I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Thank you,

Toni

Comment: It helps if you also post the image so we can all quickly see what's wrong with it. In this case it turned out you wanted "ordered by descending order of bin-count".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the plotting order of a factor, you need to change to order of the factor levels.
There are several ways to do this. I prefer to recreate the factor using `factor(..., levels=new_levels)`. In your case, you want to reorder the levels using cuts$se.fit.

The following code is a bit ugly, but it gets the job done:

```
cuts$cut = factor(as.character(cuts$cut), 
                  levels=levels(cuts$cut)[order(cuts$se.fit, decreasing=TRUE)])
```

[image]